# Laravel dynamic routing performance issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I wonder if there is any performance issue with regards to dynamically loading routes via database.

In the `routes.php`, it will retrieve values from the database and create the routing from there.

From the `routes.php`:

```
buildDynamicRoutes(new App\Factory\ModelFactory('App\Models\RoutingModel'));

function buildDynamicRoutes($model)
{
    $routes = $model->getInstance()->getRoutes(); // 'routes' is the table name wherein routes will be stored.
    if (is_array($routes) && !empty($routes)) {
        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            Route::resource($route['url'], 'DynamicController');
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, on the `buildDynamicRoutes` method, it will call the ModelFactory that instantiates the `RoutingModel` class. Once instantiated, it will connect to the API thru the `getRoutes()` method that will return the routes result.

From there, it will build the `Route::resource` base on the `$route['url']` returned which will use the `DynamicController`.

Having this structure, will there be any performance issue with regards to routing or loading the web app? I'm asking this because I notice that my web app seems to load very slow, around 10-18 seconds page load.

I recently upgraded from Codeigniter to Laravel 5.2 and notice the drastic performance issue upon switching to Laravel. When I was previously using Codeigniter, the page loads in about 2-4 seconds only. Notice the huge difference it made.

Same logic, just re-write the code base on Laravel's standards.

Comment: Codeigniter is faster than laravel

Comment: I've never seen something like this in Laravel. Usually the routes are static and then cached via the route caching mechanism. Also, try Lumen which has a faster router.

Comment: Try using route caching (I don't know if it will work for your example) but if it does then don't forget to re-cache your routes every time you create a new one ``php artisan route:cache``

Comment: For starters 2-4 seconds is **a lot** in terms of [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte), so your CodeIgniter performance was not good to begin with. Aside from that you should explain explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve: why do you need the routes to be loaded from the database, how many routes are stored in the database, etc. Knowing more details would help us propose a good implementation.

Comment: One thing stands out from the start: **you should not be generating the route definitions on every request**. @ahmad's suggestion about caching your routes is a very good one. You can have a look [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464689/laravel-how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-route-is-there-a-better-practice/35465618#35465618) that shows how you can build and cache routes programatically only when needed, not on every request.

Comment: @ahmad I wonder what's the difference between the `php artisan route:cache` and the `Cache` facade code as stated below by @fmgonzalez

Comment: @user1781041 It seems artisan command can have some issues with dynamic generated and closure routes. I´ve created an API Rest and each resource is added dynamically to routes in a foreach statement with controllers named also dynamically. I´ll try this artisan command to check it.

Comment: @fmgonzalez Instead of dynamic routes, I converted them to be hard-coded instead then did a route cache via artisan command. And guess what. From 10-18 seconds of page load I now got less than a second of page load!! Around 0.2 - 0.8!!! What a huge increase!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let us know how it goes.

```
 $routes = Cache::has('routes')
               ? Cache::get('routes')
               : $model->getInstance()->getRoutes();
 if (!Cache::has('routes')) {
    Cache::add('routes', $routes, 120); 
 }
```

Replace with your "$routes = $model->getInstance()->getRoutes()" assignament. Maybe you need to import Cache:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
```

If your $routes values change frecuently you can set another cache time instead of 120 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for this. I wanted to know what is the difference of having this code versus doing this command: `php artisan route:cache`? Also, when running this command, I encounter an error of `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Cannot redeclare buildDynamicRoutes() (previously declared ...)` There is no where this method is declared except on the routes file which makes it weird why it is treating it as a duplicate method when it is only declared once.

Comment: Not sure. I think artisan command is better when you don't have many changes in your routes.

Comment: To avoid the redeclare error you can include your function declaration in a `if (! function_exists('buildDynamicRoutes'))` statement.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot! I wonder why is it happening? A bug maybe?

Comment: If I run the `php artisan route:cache` command, is the above code still needed or will it be redundant?